# A large number of cursors , one pipelined function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have code like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT (ssn NUMBER(9), 
name VARCHAR2(30), address VARCHAR2(100));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_tab AS TABLE OF person_typ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_pipe(p_in VARCHAR2) RETURN t_tab PIPELINED IS
     rec person_typ;

     CURSOR cur1 IS
          SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */

     CURSOR cur2 IS
          SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */

     CURSOR cur3 IS
          SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */

     CURSOR cur4 IS
          SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */

     CURSOR cur5 IS
          SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */
BEGIN
    FOR cur IN cur1 LOOP
        rec := r_inc(cur.ssn, cur.name, cur.address);
        PIPE ROW(rec);
    END LOOP; 

    FOR cur IN cur2 LOOP
        rec := r_inc(cur.ssn, cur.name, cur.address);
        PIPE ROW(rec);
    END LOOP; 

    FOR cur IN cur3 LOOP
        rec := r_inc(cur.ssn, cur.name, cur.address);
        PIPE ROW(rec);
    END LOOP; 

    FOR cur IN cur4 LOOP
        rec := r_inc(cur.ssn, cur.name, cur.address);
        PIPE ROW(rec);
    END LOOP; 

    FOR cur IN cur5 LOOP
        rec := r_inc(cur.ssn, cur.name, cur.address);
        PIPE ROW(rec);
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

My problem is that my pipelined function is oogly - I have to have five cursors (this is independent of me), but I dont want to have five for loops. I would prefer have only one loop and one PIPE ROW(rec) statement ... is any way to concatenate result into one collection and then iter them?

Comment: Who knows.  We don't know how the five cursor queries are related, if at all.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, cursor queries returns the same type of data - three values - ssn NUMBER(9), name VARCHAR2(30), address VARCHAR2(100).

Comment: Where that restriction of 5 cursors comes from (a non-modifiable legacy code) ? If you don't like your current implementation you should work harder to make it possible to combine the cursors into one as suggested by @GordonLinoff. Every PL/SQL cursor requires a dedicated fetch (or a "loop"). It makes no sense to say I want `x` cursors and `y` loops. PL/SQL cursor can be considered as a SQL collection, but you can't join those collections (without fetching). IMO `bulk collect into` would be inferior to your current solution.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm, how about using `union all` and only one cursor?

```
 CURSOR cur1 IS
      SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ssn, name, address FROM /* ... complex query */
```

Comment: If OP follows your advice, don't think he needs the function anymore (maybe a view instead), unless there is more logic in the function he's not showing.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, you replaced the five cursors one. I have to have five cursors (this is independent of me), I would rather prefer gather data to one collection and then return in one loop... if possible ofc.

Comment: @DavidSilva This is the optimal (PL/)SQL solution.